# Moment.js ignores day of week during parsing validation

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to check string being a valid date string.
But I can't validate day of week in string representation.

These two commands show similar result:

```
moment("Tuesday 19/09/2017", "dddd D/M/YYYY", true).isValid()  //true
moment("Tuesday 20/09/2017", "dddd D/M/YYYY", true).isValid()  //true
```

How can I check it? I can't split this string in two parts, because I don't really know the format.

Comment: What does this "I can't split this string in two parts, because I don't really know the format." mean. What format do you not know? What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear isValid is only checking the date part.

If you want to check the whole string, maybe one idea is to parse it, if the result is the same after re-formating it then it's valid.

eg.

```js
function valid(dt,fmt) {
  return moment(dt, fmt).format(fmt) === dt;
}

let fmt = 'dddd D/M/YYYY';
let dates = [
  "Tuesday 19/9/2017",
  "Tuesday 20/9/2017"
];

dates.forEach((dt) => {
  console.log(dt + ' ' + valid(dt, fmt));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```